# Reason why this calculation gives wrong probability

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Note that this question is [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484728/the-kabrastan-park-probability-question). I do have solution. But I want to know specifically what's the flaw in following approach.

> Question: You are lost in the National park of Kabrastan. The park population consists of tourists and Kabrastanis. Tourists comprise two-thirds of the population the park and give a correct answer to requests for directions with probability $\frac{3}{4}$. The air of Kabrastan has an amnesaic quality, however, and so the answers to repeated questions to tourists are independent, even if the question and the person are the same. If you ask a Kabrastani for directions, the answer is always wrong.
>   Suppose you ask a randomly chosen passer-by whether the exit from the park is East or West. The answer is East. You then ask the same person again, and the reply is again East. What is the probability of East being correct?

Following is my approach which I know is wrong but I don't know what's the flaw in that.

$A: \text{East is indeed the right way to exit.}$

$B: \text{Passer answers east two times.}$

Let's condition upon weather passer chosen is tourist or Kabrastani.

**Case 1: Passer chosen is tourist.**

then,
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B|A)*P(A) + P(B|A')*P(A')} = \frac{\frac{9}{16}*\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{9}{16}*\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{16}*\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{9}{10}$

**Case 2: Passer chosen is Kabrastani.**

here, $P(A|B) = 0$ because, we know that is Kabrastani gives answer as east it is definitely not the right way to go.

So, required probability = $P(\text{passer chosen is tourist})*P((A|B)|\text{passer chosen is tourist}) + P(\text{passer chosen is Kabrastani})*P((A|B)|\text{passer chosen is Kabrastani})$

= $\frac{2}{3}*\frac{9}{10} + \frac{1}{3} * 0 = \frac{3}{5}$

But answer given is $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Hint:  The fact that the person answers $E$ twice in a row is evidence that they are local.

Comment: Yes, I just corrected it.

Comment: So basically I should not condition upon whether the passer is local or not because probability of being local changes with evidence that answer gets repeated. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your solution also pre-supposes that $P(A)=\frac12$ even though that is the variable you are trying to find.

Comment: $P(A)$ is the probability of east being right without any other information and we want to find $P(A|\text{passer gives east as answer two consecutive times.})$ Still it is incorrect?

Comment: And I found my mistake and fixed it and got actual answer. I just have to consider appropriate probability for in last step. i.e that for $P(\text{passer chosen is tourist})$ which is not $\frac{2}{3}$ as I have written. That comes to be $\frac{10}{18}.$